# Gnome - touchpad gesturers

Tags: gnome, arch-linux, gestures

I am using gnome 3.17.90 on XPS 13 2015 , arch linux. I tried use xf86-input-libinput. The touchpad works well as a mouse and for scrolling up and down.

I dont understand how can I make the multitouch for 3 and 4 fingers to work correctly. Zoom In ,Zoom Out...

I tried also with synaptic and the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[libinput-gestures](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures)**

Config: XPS 13 (9360) Antergos/Gnome

Mark Blakeney's [libinput-gestures](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures), available via AUR, is a simple and low friction solution that basically digests the output from `libinput-debug-events`, mapping gestures to configurable commands with sensible defaults. I lost hours trying other options without success but had this one up and running in minutes.

Comment: At the time of writing, this looks to only be able to emit boolean events, and at the end of the gesture. i.e. you can trigger a command at the *end* of a pinch {in|out}, but you can't have a pinch command that updates in realtime or that is dependent on the *amount* of pinch. That said, libinput-debug-events does expose that information, and Mark Blakeney's script does process these updates internally - it just doesn't expose them.

Answer (score 1):

The xf86-input-synaptics driver does not support multitouch (beyond two-finger-scroll).

While libinput supports MT in general, this is currently not yet exposed by the xf86 driver, since libinput exposes high-level *gestures* and not low-level individual touches, and there's no X11 extension for that yet – only Gtk3 on Wayland will recognize them.

(Also, currently libinput's gesture recognition is fairly limited...)

Comment: so if I using gnome on wayland how can I achieve MT?

Comment: Exact same situation here. XPS 13 (2015), Arch Linux, Gnome 3.18 and libinput as input driver. Gnome is started in wayland mode, but still doesn't interpret any gestures.